# Why does my localhost application on Node.js take so long/refuse to connect?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, microsoft-edge

Why does my localhost:3000 application take so long to load? I have tried quite a lot of ways to solve this, such as:

1. Disable IPv6
2. Add localhost into the `hosts` file
3. Update npm and node.js to the latest version

The localhost doesn't load, and eventually, just stops loading and refuses to connect. I don't know why this is happening. I am using Microsoft Edge and Windows 10.

Here is my code:

```
//jshint esversion:6
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
   response.send("Hello World");
});

app.listen(3000, function()
{
   console.log("Server is listening on port 3000.");
});
```

Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: It used to load at least a little bit but never fully loaded, now it just refuses to connect. :(

Comment: Let's eliminate DNS issues: does it go faster if you use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: No, not really, it still gives the exact same "refuses to connect" page.

Comment: What's the output on the console where you're running the application?

Comment: "Server is listening on Port 3000", so I think the server is running, however, the browser page just doesn't load.

Comment: Check your firewall. You can also try with `curl` from the command line.

Comment: It worked, finally, thanks @Thomas

Comment: The command line exited the node application, but from my side, it said it was still running. It must have just been a bug. I restarted my pc and it worked!

Comment: From your last comment, it seems that you have solved the issue. You can put your solution as an answer and mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command line exited the node application, but from my side, it said it was still running. It must have just been a bug. I restarted my pc and it worked.